# Mostrar fecha de ayer con formato MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, date

Tengo esta consulta:

```
SELECT *
FROM tabla
```

Me trae todos los registros, quiero traer solo los de la fecha de hoy:

```
SELECT *
FROM tabla 
WHERE fecha = DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(), "%d/%m/%Y")
```

Eso me imprime la fecha así:

**19/11/2020**

Ahora, ¿Cómo hago para ver el día de ayer con ese formato?  Es decir que la fecha se vea así: **18/11/2020**

Comment: `The CURDATE() function returns the current date.` - La funcion CURDATE() retorna la fecha actual. Si quieres consultar por otra fecha dentro del `WHERE`, debes ingresar esa fecha como parametro

Comment: WHERE FECHA = '2020-11-18'

Comment: Lo sé, pero la quiero restarle un día al CURDATE() y mostrarlo con el formato que yo desee. @Excorpion

Comment: Eso sería prudente desde un parámetro, pero quiero hacerlo restándole un día al CURDATE() @Srsole

Comment: Ahh lo que tu quieres es darle formato a las fechas durante la salida

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_subdate y también checa acá: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se puede hacer de la siguiente manera:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY), "%d/%m/%Y") as 'Ayer';
```

El resultado para el día de hoy obviamente será:

[image: query result]

La función `date_sub` es la que te permite restarle un intervalo de tiempo a una fecha dada, dicho intervalo puede ser:

- MICROSECOND
- SECOND
- MINUTE
- HOUR
- DAY
- WEEK
- MONTH
- QUARTER
- YEAR
- SECOND_MICROSECOND
- MINUTE_MICROSECOND
- MINUTE_SECOND
- HOUR_MICROSECOND
- HOUR_SECOND
- HOUR_MINUTE
- DAY_MICROSECOND
- DAY_SECOND
- DAY_MINUTE
- DAY_HOUR
- YEAR_MONTH

Comment: Esta es la respuesta que estaba buscando, muchas gracias

Answer (score 2):

Si quieres retornar una fecha, con otro formato durante la consulta
No se hace dentro del `WHERE`,
debes hacerlo durante el `SELECT`, 
luego simplemente lees la fecha nueva que has creado en la consulta.

```
SELECT * , DATE_FORMAT(fecha,'%d/%m/%Y') as fecha2
FROM tabla
WHERE fecha = '2020-11-18'
```

---

Si además de eso, quieres que no se muestre el resultado de la columna 'fecha'. Debes excluirla dentro del select, y pasar aquellos datos que si estarás ocupando:

```
SELECT columna1, columna2, DATE_FORMAT(fecha,'%d/%m/%Y') as fecha2
FROM tabla
WHERE fecha = '2020-11-18'
```

Comment: Gracias, pero aunque mantienes el formato sigues seteando la fecha **(fecha = '2020-11-18')** y lo que yo busco es hacer algo como `dia - 1`

Comment: Si, eso lo entendi en la respuesta de Ruslan, tu buscas restar siempre 1 dia al dia actual. No necesariamente a hoy 19, sino al dia que se haga la consulta. Pero como dije, eso es durante el select, no durante el where